SQL Server : consistent data encryption/masking while read
I would like to check with you regarding dynamic data encryption/masking when reading from a SQL Server database.
To elaborate further, the data elements should be encrypted/masked when a set of users querying the tables. The data stored at rest should be clear (i.e. unmasked/ not encrypted).
Also, the masking values should be consistent across the database.
E.g. if a username john - masked/encrypted to xyz in schema 1 table a, schema 2 table b should have the same masked/encrypted value for the same user. So that we can join the cross-schema tables.
Key notes:

Data at rest should be in clear form i.e. unchanged from source.
Encryption/masking should be consistent

I have explored the SQL Server TDE & DDE options but doesn't suit my requirements.
Would like to hear from experts who handled such a requirement in a SQL Server database.

You can't join on masked value because masking loses information. If John becomes XXXX and Mark becomes XXXX, the join between them will be very bad.

With that being said, i think dynamic data masking is the feature you want. Why not give it a spin? Note that it's not 100% secure because some clever tricks can be used to fish out the masked data

I need the masking values to be consistent across, so that cross - schema analysis can be obtained. Dynamic data masking option is giving consistent masking values. Hence it's ruled out from my option
